# cmd asking for administrator privileges in windows 8

Tags: windows-8, wireless-networking

I'm trying to make an ad hoc connection in command prompt but it keeps telling me I need administrator privileges even thou I'm logged in as the administrator. Any possible solutions?

Answer (score 0):

right click on the CMD link (for command prompt) and select 'run as administrator'. Just being logged in as administrator is not enough.

As a shortcut you can do Windows-X and select 'Command Prompt (Admin)'